# C# UWP Drag And Drop File/Folder Permission

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, drag-and-drop, uwp-xaml

I am learning c# and making my first UWP app with it. Bit stuck on a folder/file permission problem. The app I am making is a file renaming app where i want the user to drag and drop a bunch of files and folders onto a `<ListView/>`, the `<ListView/>` will scan the dropped items and display the filenames, then the app is supposed to loop over the files one by one and rename them according to whatever options the user selects.

However, the app does not have permissions to the dropped files. The only way (as far as my research has led me to believe) to allow the app to modify the file names is by using a File Picker and allowing the user to select the files he wants to rename manually thereby granting permissions to modify them. This is a potential solution to my problem but it means that i cannot use the drag and drop functionality that i think is a much more elegant solution.

So my question is whether there is a way to grant permission to the files and folders the user drops onto the `<ListView/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's not much you can do about the given read-only permission. Except for maybe leaving your voice on [uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/10911696-universal-apps-drag-drop-remove-read-only-attr).